# creating different Circle shapes in css

Tags: html, css

I want a shape like this.

[image]

But I have tried following code

```css
.halfCircleRight{
   height: 70px;
   width: 40px;
   border-radius: 0 90px 90px 0;
   background: #000000;       
}
```

```html
<div class="halfCircleRight">
```

But I'm  not able to achieve full output. I'm facing difficulty to create[this shape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r6mSS.jpg). Could any one can help me to create this shape

Answer (score 0):

This may help you..

```css
body{margin:0 }

.halfCircle1{  
   height: 100px;
   width: 100px;
   border-radius: 90px 90px 90px 90px;
   background: white;   
}
.halfCircle3{ 
   position:absolute;
   z-index:-1;
   top:50px;
   left:50px;
   height: 100px;
   width: 100px;
   border-radius: 90px 90px 90px 90px;
   background: #000000;       
}
```

```html
<div class="halfCircle1"></div>
<div class="halfCircle1"></div>
<div class="halfCircle3"></div>
```

Comment: so you want [this](geometrydaily.tumblr.com/image/126507813677].) shape.?